# setting up texmaker with knitr on linux

Tags: r, knitr, texmaker

I am trying to change the R Sweave command to knitr on linux. The current (R Sweave) command is found under options > configure:

```
R CMD Sweave %.Rnw
```

Yihui gives and example of how to do this on windows [here](http://yihui.name/knitr/demo/editors/).

How would you do this on linux (ubuntu)?

Comment: ... what exactly doesn't work with Yihui's suggestion for you?

Comment: His suggestion is:
`Rscript.exe -e "knitr::knit2pdf('%.Rnw')"`

Comment: You should add what you actually tried to the question.

Comment: sorry just now saw the footnote which says:

`Rscript -e "knitr::knit2pdf('%.Rnw')"`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Rscript` isn't called by using `Rscript.exe` on Linux.  Just change Rscript.exe to `Rscript`.

Comment: Any idea how to extend the command above to open produced pdf file in internal viewer?

Comment: Isn't there a separate option for setting the viewer stuff?  I'm not at my linux box right now so I can't check...

Comment: Is there a problem with clicking the View PDF button once after you compile the document?  The PDF should be updated automatically after each compilation

Answer (score 1):

I just wanted to add that I just discovered that the abovementioned code does not work when child Rnw documents are included with `\Sexpr{knit_child('path')}`.

Use `Rscript -e "library(knitr); knit('%.Rnw')"` instead.

Please mention in the comments if you know of any difference in output between `knit::knit2pdf()` and `knit()`.